# $\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$ be set of all $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrices over $\mathbb R$. Which of the following are true?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

> $\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$ be set of all $n \times n$ diagonalizable
>   matrices over $\mathbb R$. Which of the following are true?
>
> (a) Subspace of $\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb R)$
>
> (b) Connected
>
> (c) Compact
>
> (d) Dense
>
> (e) None of the above

(a) $O$ matrix is in $\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$. $A \in\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$, then $kA \in \mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$ $\forall\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. I am not able to prove the statement 'suppose $A,B \in \mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$ then $A+B \in \mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)'$.

(b)If I could prove it is a subspace, I can prove it is path connected, hence it is a connected space in the set of all matrices.

(c)I don't think it is bounded with respect to Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R^{n^2}}$. Hence it is not compact.

(d) I don't know how to approximate any matrices with elements of $\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$

Please help me to judge the answer.

Comment: some related posts might help - [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620613/is-the-set-of-all-diagonalizable-matrices-compact) , [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459522/density-of-diagonalizable-matrices)!

Comment: thanks, @BAYMAX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a) $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ are both diagonalizable but their sum isn't.

b) $\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$ is indeed path-connected: each element has a path to the identity matrix: if $A=PDP^{-1}$, consider $\gamma:t\mapsto P((1-t)D+tI)P^{-1}$.

c) $\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$ is clearly unbounded as you noticed.

d)Consider the mapping $f:\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto (a-d)^2+4bc$.

$f(M)$ is the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of $M$. When $M$ is diagonalizable, $f(M)\geq 0$. There are matrices with no real eigenvalues. For these matrices, $f$ is $<0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\mathbb{D}(n;\mathbb R)$ cannot be dense.

Comment: For (c) $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&n+1 \end{pmatrix}$ i judged because, for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists$ a matrix like this whose norm greater than n. Am I correct?

Comment: (d) Using the continuity of $f$, how can I say $\mathbb{D}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not dense?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan reason by contradiction

Comment: We want to prove " $f$ is continuous $\implies$ $\mathbb{D}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not dense                                                                                        Suppose $\mathbb{D}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is dense $\implies$ $A\in M(n,\mathbb{R})$, $\exists$ a sequence in $\mathbb{D}(n,\mathbb{R})$ , which converges to $A$. This much I can draw. How to proceed further?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan first thing, $n=2$. Then choose some $A$ with no real eigenvalue. Hence $f(A)<0$. For a sequence $B_n$ that converges to $A$, $f(B_n)\geq 0$ for all $n$, and by continuity of $f$, $0 \leq f(B_n)\to f(A)<0$, a contradiction.

Comment: ok. I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: How to prove for $n$?